# cs50P. Basic question on terminal mode navigation

Tags: navigation

I'm using visual studio code with windows. I can type "python" command in terminal window to get into interactive mode (ie, going from "$" to ">>>"), but how do i toggle out of interactive mode to continue coding my program? thx

Answer (score 0):

You can exit the interactive prompt by pressing either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or typing `exit()` into the terminal, followed by enter.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> sends an EOF marker to the python REPL, which will cause it to exit.

Comment: Thank you!  This newbie appreciates your help.